# Handy tools for plotting and analysing OMNeT++ simulation and how to install and use them

Tags: omnet++

I want to use tools such as GNUPlot and Plove which are handy tools for plotting and analyzing OMNeT++ simulation. How to install them?
Are there newer tools with this goal?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Neither GNUPlot nor Plove cannot be directly use with OMNeT++. But one can export any OMNeT++ results to *.csv file and proceed using these programs.

Comment: How to install them?

Comment: In Ubuntu: sudo apt install gnuplot , in Windows: download installer and install it.